After installing pachyderm the pods are in ImagePullBackOff
I am trying to follow the Pachyderm installation with miniKube (although my goal is to actually do the example with OpenCV)
I don't use brew, and I already had docker installed in my ubuntu machine
I installed minikube with
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64
sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube && rm minikube-linux-amd64

and then did minikube start
I installed kubectl with
sudo curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.30.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
sudo chmod +x ./kubectl
sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

and I installed Pachctl CLI with
curl -o /tmp/pachctl.deb -L https://github.com/pachyderm/pachyderm/releases/download/v2.9.4/pachctl_2.9.4_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i /tmp/pachctl.deb

and helm with
curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/main/scripts/get-helm-3
chmod 700 get_helm.sh
./get_helm.sh

and
helm repo add pachyderm https://helm.pachyderm.com  
helm repo update  

Finally I installed pachyderm with
    helm install pachyderm pachyderm/pachyderm --set deployTarget=LOCAL --set proxy.enabled=true --set proxy.service.type=LoadBalancer

NAME: pachyderm
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Apr 24 11:57:53 2024
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
NOTES:
WARNING: legacy storage configuration options will be deprecated in 2.10.0 and removed in 2.11.0.
Please set 'gocdkEnabled: true' to enable new storage configuration options and use 'storageURL' to configure your storage bucket.

However after I do this when I type kubectl get po -A I get
NAMESPACE     NAME                                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
default       console-5f99dd8f68-cq6ln                     0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0             69m
default       etcd-0                                       0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0             69m
default       pachd-99bb7b6b9-r2gcd                        0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0             69m
default       pachyderm-kube-event-tail-76887dc9f7-bbjd7   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0             69m
default       pachyderm-loki-0                             0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0             69m
default       pachyderm-promtail-69jsn                     0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0             69m
default       pachyderm-proxy-5c65cdcb87-92rqj             0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0             69m
default       pg-bouncer-68f869c55b-jzmrj                  0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0             69m
default       postgres-0                                   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0             69m
kube-system   coredns-7db6d8ff4d-pmmsh                     1/1     Running            0             18h
kube-system   etcd-minikube                                1/1     Running            0             18h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube                      1/1     Running            0             18h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube             1/1     Running            0             18h
kube-system   kube-proxy-tmmh7                             1/1     Running            0             18h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube                      1/1     Running            0             18h
kube-system   storage-provisioner                          1/1     Running            1 (18h ago)   18h

So the pods are not Running as expected
This is my first time with minikube in fact so can someone tell me how can I solve this and continue with pachyderm? I have just started learning minikube by the way
